# Meaning of "pitches add up"

Tags: nouns, meaning-in-context, meaning

I would like to know the meaning of the phrase "pitch adds up" as it appears in [this phrase from an article in *Fast Company*](http://www.fastcompany.com/3003010/how-official-getting-things-done-app-will-free-your-mind-and-empty-your-inboxes):

> None of [the applications] fit the bill, and the pitches add up quickly.

According to dictionaries, *pitch* has a whole range of meanings, and I don't know which exactly applies in this case.

Comment: This needs more context.  My guess is that someone is evaluating the suitability of some applications for their purpose by listening to proposals *pitching* (i.e., a sales pitch) each one.  But listening to each pitch takes up time and so far that time spent has not yielded a suitable application.

Comment: You haven’t told us enough.  There is too much context missing, and that is where the answer lies.  Just exactly where is this from, and what are the previous few sentences?

Comment: I've added a link to the article itself where the questionable phrase was found.

Comment: I see.  It's not the applications that don't fit the bill.  It's that reading each email that is asking for the GTD seal-of-approval (essentially a pitch from each application's developer) takes too much time.  *pitch* is used in the sense of a sales pitch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quote in question is this one:

> Skip any email that asks for the official Getting Things Done (GTD) blessing for a task-management app. None of them fit the bill, and the pitches add up quickly. "One a week, for the last five years,"

The pitches are the emails that advertise task-management apps and they add up since he receives one of these every week and has done so for five years.